# Indefinite integral of $\ln\big(\arccos(5x)/\arcsin(3x)\big)$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, logarithms, indefinite-integrals

> Find $$\int\,\ln\left(\frac{\arccos(5x)}{\arcsin(3x)}\right)\,\text{d}x\,.$$

Can anyone find this one for me please or at least give me the steps to work it out please.

Comment: Use https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Difference_of_Logarithms and http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IntegrationbyParts.html

Comment: [This may be useful](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5Bln(arccos(5x)%2Farcsin(3x)),x%5D).

Comment: @Decaf-Math this link 1) isn't useful because it cannot give the method to follow 2) I have tried it with a failure to give an answer

Comment: @Gady-ManuelAlaoui Normally I would respect the hold and not comment, but this question is so tricky that I feel it is unreasonable to expect you to "show your work".  I will give a series of comments that provide an outline of the solution.

Comment: First of all, my understanding is that $\int [(cos u)/u] \;du$ has no closed form, so it is integrated as an infinite limit via the taylor series : $cos(u) = 1 - u^2/2! + u^4/4! - u^6/6! + ...$

Comment: Since $\ln(a/b) = \ln(a) - \ln(b),$ the problem reduces to $\int \ln[\text{arccos}(nx)]\;dx$.

Comment: I only attacked $I = \int \ln[\text{arccos}(x) \;dx.$  Using the substitution $u = \text{arccox}(x)$ implies that $x=\cos u$ implies that $dx = -\sin u \;du.$  Therefore, $I = \int \ln(u) (-\sin u) du.$

Comment: Using integration by parts, $I = \ln(u)\cos(u) - \int [(\cos u)/u] \;du.$  Re one of my previous comments, this completes the problem, at least as far as $\int \ln[\text{arccos}(x)] \;dx$ is concerned.

Comment: Thanks a lot @user2661923